# Why is the elemental volume of a sphere equal to $4 \pi r^2dr$?

Tags: geometry, calculus, approximations

I was doing this question on calculating the electric field at a certain point in a sphere (length $r$ away from the centre), where the charge density is given by an equation.
When I checked the solution to this question, it said to calculate elemental charge $dQ$ for the elemental volume of the sphere $dV$, using the charge density equation.
It says that the volume between two concentric shells within the sphere, at distances $r$ and $r+dr$ is

$$dV = \frac{4\pi(r+dr)^3}{3} - \frac{4\pi(r)^3}{3} = \frac{4\pi(3r^2dr + 3rdr^2 + dr^3))}{3}.$$

Now, why is this equal to  $4 \pi r^2dr$?

Comment: The heuristic employed in this calculation is that, since $dr$ is very small, squaring or cubing it makes it much smaller. Hence the terms $3rdr^2$ and $dr^3$ are negligible and can just be dropped.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with physics ! Please ask on a mathematics q&a website. Actually @sourisse gave you the correct answer.

Comment: I think this is quite relevant to physics actually, it is an approximation/method/tool that is used a *lot* in physics, e.g. electrostatics, gravitation, solid state etc etc etc

Comment: BTW you can also think of $4\pi r^2 dr$ as the volume of a spherical shell with radius $r$ and thickness $dr$ - just surface area multiplied by thickness

Comment: @FraSchelle I think if you asked this on math.stackexchange, you would be directed here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sourisse's comment answers your question, but just for the record I'll expand on it here as a Wiki answer. Note that this is a physicist's answer - any mathemticians present would be wise to avert their gaze now.

Remember that when we say that the volume element is:

$$ dV = 4\pi r^2 dr \tag{1} $$

We are talking about the limit in which $dr \rightarrow 0$. If $dr$ is extremely small then $dr^2$ is extremely extremely small and $dr^3$ is extremely extremely extremely small. So in the limit of $dr \rightarrow 0$ we can simply ignore the higher powers and your full equation turns into equation (1).

Comment: Sir this is the same thing which was taught to us, but is there any way of using the terms of $(dr)^2$ or any higher power in calculation or integration? Thank you alot!

Answer (score 4):

$v =\dfrac{4}{3}\pi r^3$

Differentiating with respect to $r$

$\dfrac{dv}{dr}=4\pi r^2$

$dv =4\pi r^2 dr$

Comment: right on!  this is the kind of elementary "trick" too often forgotten.  Pity you can't get the $\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi$ factor from $4\pi$ in this way.